# cannot import android.os.strictmode

Tags: android, android-strictmode

on developing an android app with webservices. which uses :

```
     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
         android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

I am facing problem while importing `import android.os.StrictMode;` (it cannot be resolved)
my code is giving me an exception "`java.net.SocketException: Permission denied for android`"
because of this.if the strictmode is not supported in api 8 . what is the alternative for it?

Comment: why do you need StrictMode anyway ?

Comment: ("permission denied" would rather indicate a lack of internet permission)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey StrictMode Class was introduced in API Level 9 and your project target is API Level 8. Please Refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html). So You are getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the AndroidManifest.xml file

In your File the minSdkVersion is 8

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Change The SDK version to 9 like shown below

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
```

it will solve your problem.

And see below link for more information about StrictMode.

[Android - StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to go with API Level 8.

Check this link :

[Android StrictMode for all platform versions](http://www.simpligility.com/2011/01/android-strictmode-for-all-platform-versions/)

Thanks.